# How to Filter/Search List in Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a TV show and movie app, so I'm trying to write html code. I want to filter the list for p code, but I didn't understand that the code I wrote didn't work. Can you help me fix this? Thank you very much in advance

Sorry if the article is not understood. Google Translate :)

yazdım yazızağımı canım benim yazdım artık kabul edermisin ? hadi

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
  
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
  
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, p, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        txtValue = p.textContent || p.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-wrapper {
    background-color: #222731 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }


}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="go:home" class="brand-logo center"><img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/vnA3QY.png" width="150" height="auto" /></a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>

<ul id="myUL" class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><div class="user-view">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/ldhP0w.png">
      </div>
      <center>
      <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="https://i.hizliresim.com/mYJBzd.png"></a>
      <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">Dizifast</span></a>
      </center>
    </div></li>
          <li><a href="go:home">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
      <li class="no-padding">
        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
          <li>
            <a class="collapsible-header">Diziler<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="go:yabanciden">Yabancı Diziler</a></li>
                <li><a href="go:yerlidizi">Yerli Diziler</a></li>
                <li><a href="go:cizgifilm">Çizgi Diziler</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="no-padding">
        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
          <li>
            <a class="collapsible-header">Filmer<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="go:yabancison">Yabancı Filmler</a></li>
                <li><a href="go:yerlifilm">Yerli Filmler</a></li>
                <li><a href="go:seri">Seri Filmler</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="go:belgesel">Belgeseller</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- ALT KISIM -->
    
    
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul class="collection blue-grey darken-3">
    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:opbuff11">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/operation-buffalo_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Operation Buffalo</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 1. Bölüm</p><span class="orange darken-4 white-text badge">Yeni Dizi</span></a>
      <a href="go:opbuff11" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:snowpie13">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/snowpiercer-hd_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Snowpiercer</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 3. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:snowpie13" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:stargir13">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/dc-stargirl_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Stargirl</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 3. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:stargir13" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:rick410">
      <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/OwSJ3H.png" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Rick and Morty</b><br/>
      4. Sezon 10. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:rick410" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:thelumi13">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/the-luminaries_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>The Luminaries</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 3. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:thelumi13" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

   <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:pennyc16">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/penny-dreadful-city-of-angels_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Penny Dreadful: City of Angels</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 6. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:penny16" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:killeve38">
      <img src="https://yabancidizi.vip/uploads/series/killing-eve_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Killing Eve</b><br/>
      3. Sezon 8. Bölüm</p></a>
      <a href="go:killeve38" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:blinds5.1">
      <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/wBVBbl.png" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Blindspot</b><br/>
      5. Sezon 1. Bölüm</p><span class="orange accent-3 white-text badge">Yeni Sezon</span></a>
      <a href="go:blinds5.1" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>

    <li class="collection-item avatar "><a href="go:upload">
      <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/UHS6rf.png" alt="" class="circle">
     <p style="color:black;"><b>Upload</b><br/>
      1. Sezon 1-8. Bölüm</p><span class="orange accent-4 white-text badge">Yeni Dizi</span></a>
      <a href="go:upload" class="secondary-content"><i style="color:#ff9100;" class="fas fa-closed-captioning"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

   
   
   

<style> body { background-color: #222731; } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the errors before we can help with the filter.

[image]

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` usually occurs when trying to use jQuery before it is loaded. Make sure you are loading jQuery before any of your own code. It should be served in this order:

jQuery >
Materialize >
Custom JS

Also, you just need one document.ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

Can you explain better what the filter should do?